# Easiest way to react on cursor keys (arrows) in interactive shell script

Tags: shell, terminal, key, arrow-keys, text-cursor

I'd like to write a shell script which shall be interactive and react on the use of cursor keys.  My current approach seems a little complicated.  I would determine the escape sequence for the cursor keys using `tput kcud1` etc. and then use `read -s -n 1 a` to read byte-by-byte, append the byte to a collected string, and then compare the collected string to the determined escape sequences.  If one matches, then I can react.

This is problematic because I've got no idea where an escape sequence ends.  For instance, `tput kcud1` (down arrow) here returns `"\eOB"`.  I would use a timeout in order to ignore unknown escape sequences (and probably start over if an escape character arrives).  This all doesn't look nice to me.

Isn't there a simpler way of reacting on arrow key usage in a shell script?

Comment: Some inspiration here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679188/casing-arrow-keys-in-bash

Comment: Yeah I found that as well during research but it has no proper answer I could accept.

Comment: The problem I see is that we do not have a function telling us that an escape sequence is still unfinished.