# How can I use Arrow key with general keys in shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to use arrow keys with general keys.

For example)

```
read -s -n 3 key

case ${key} in

^[[A)

     echo "UP"
     ;;
"d")

     echo "d"
     ;;
"s")

     echo "s"
     ;;
esac
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Casing arrow keys in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679188/casing-arrow-keys-in-bash)