# Bash Script - Map ASCII Characters to Corresponding Unicode Characters in Defined Strings

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to map a fixed set of ASCII characters to a fixed set of Unicode characters. I.e., for each digit 0-9, I want to get the circled digit equivalent.

```
mapFrom="0123456789"
mapTo="➀➁➂➃➄➅➆➇➈"

today=20221018

#convert to "➁➁➁➀➀➇"
todayWithCircles=$(do_something_here) # <-- what's the "something"?

echo $todayWithCircles
# output: ➁➁➁➀➀➇
```

Given two fixed strings of equal length, what is the easiest way to map them-- based on their position in the string-- as described?

Comment: There are a number of strategies for mapping to multi-byte keys in the post [Casing arrow keys in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10679188/3422102) though they are usually mapping the reverse of what you need. However, if you have the unicode keycode for `➀➁➂➃➄➅➆➇➈`, you should be able to do the reverse map the same way using `case`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick and dirty approach using `perl` to do the translating:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mapFrom="0123456789"
mapTo="➀➁➂➃➄➅➆➇➈"
today=20221018

perl -CSD -Mutf8 -pe "tr/$mapFrom/$mapTo/" <<<"$today"
```

outputs

```
➁➁➁➀➀➇
```

(Assuming the script is encoded in UTF-8, of course. `-CSD` tells perl to use UTF-8 encoding for standard input, output, and other opened files, `-Mutf8` tells it that the script itself (The argument to `-e`) is encoded in UTF-8.)

If you have GNU sed available, you can use it instead:

```bash
sed "y/$mapFrom/$mapTo/" <<<"$today"
```

(See [this unix stackexchange Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389615/367593) for why `tr` isn't suitable)

Comment: I am partial to the `sed` approach. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bash only, pure way of doing this.

You loop over each character of the string, and replace it with a *rounded character*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mapTo="➀➁➂➃➄➅➆➇➈"
today=0987654321

for ((i = 0; i < ${#today}; i++)); do
  echo -n "${mapTo:${today:$i:1}:1}"
done
```

result:

`➈➇➆➅➄➃➂➁➀`

Comment: Thank you for this. The `sed` approach will work a little better for me than looping, but this is a great solution!